# Resetting dynamic array with another new statement, need delete first?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic

If i have something like

```
int* thing;

thing = new int[10]

(more code...)

thing = new int[50];
```

would I need to do `delete[] thing` between them? And to be sure/safe since I"m posting anyway, there isn't any problems with doing this is there?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise the memory allocated by `new int[10]` will be leaked.

Comment: Every `new` must be balanced by a `delete`, and every `new[]` must be balanced by a `delete[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To be safe you should always delete the memory allocated on the heap, otherwise there will be memory leaks, which in future can lead to memory crunch and can cause your application to crash.**

//allocating memory on stack (stack memory will be deleted as soon as it goes out of scope, automatically by the compiler)

```
int* thing;
```

//array of 10 is allocated on heap (heap memory is the responsibility of user to delete , otherwise there will be memory leaks)

```
thing = new int[10]
```

//Ideally you should delete memory allocated on heap here, otherwise memory leak will be there, which can lead to crunch of memory in future:

```
(more code...)
delete []thing;

thing = new int[50];
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `new` to allocate memory in the heap, you need to at some point free that memory with `delete`. If you don't do this, it will lead to a memory leak. Imagine you allocate 10 spaces to `thing`, then "overwrite" it with 50 spaces. Those 10 original spaces get lost somewhere in your memory and never get freed (which is bad).